# Probs with different cells from the same table changing different background colors on hover

Tags: html, css

Ive been trying to get a simple example of different cells in the same table changing their background colors differently from each other.  I read you can assign class or ids to individual TDs so I set my code up as such with no success.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .aTD td:hover {background-color: green;}
        .bTD td:hover {background-color: yellow;}
        .cTD td:hover {background-color: red;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:95%; height:95%;" >
        <td class="aTD"><a href="#setA">A</a></td>
        <td class="bTD"><a href="#setB">B</a></td>
        <td class="cTD"><a href="#setC">C</a></td>
    </table>
</body>
```

if i replace the style script with...

```
td:hover{background-color:red;}
```

then it works but I am trying to get different colors for different cells.  What am I missing here.  It seems so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to mention TD when you have assign class to every TD tag.

```
<style>
    .aTD:hover {background-color: green;}
    .bTD:hover {background-color: yellow;}
    .cTD:hover {background-color: red;}
</style>
```